# unity quad mesh collider not following quad vertex change

Tags: mesh

its about a single quad with only 4 vertices and a meshCollider:
during Update the vertex positions are changed in each frame for some animation but the meshCollider sit fix at the original created position.

I'd googled many but nothing come close to that. I'd also tried toggled the convex checkbox but
it is also not following the size of those changes and the meshCollider stayed fix and much bigger than the actual quad.

Someone with the experience please advise.
Thanks in advance your effort will be most appreciated.

Following is the snippet of the vertex change and the mesh reCalculate lines:

```
    aniMeshColliderTest:
    switch(btn.sTarget){
    case "open":{
        btn.v3a_vertex[0].x -= btn.fDeltaX;
        btn.v3a_vertex[0].y -= btn.fDeltaY;
        btn.v3a_vertex[1].x += btn.fDeltaX;   
        btn.v3a_vertex[1].y -= btn.fDeltaY;
        btn.v3a_vertex[2].x -= btn.fDeltaX;
        btn.v3a_vertex[2].y += btn.fDeltaY;
        btn.v3a_vertex[3].x += btn.fDeltaX;
        btn.v3a_vertex[3].y += btn.fDeltaY;
        // Debug.Log("thumbPADctxSeqc2:aniMeshColliderTest:1380:btn.v3a_vertex[0].y:" + btn.v3a_vertex[0].y + ", v3a_vertex[1].y:" + btn.v3a_vertex[1].y);
    }break;         
    btn.g.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertices = btn.v3a_vertex;
    btn.g.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    btn.g.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.RecalculateBounds();
```